what is the impact of the point at the end of instruction COBOL
what is the impact of the point at the end of instruction COBOL when i use SECTION. It seem that the end point is very important.
What is the difference between:
SELECT SECTION.
    MOVE xxx TO Bbb
    MOVE ccc TO HHHH
END-SELECT.
    EXIT.

AND
SELECT SECTION.
    MOVE xxx TO Bbb.
    MOVE ccc TO HHHH.
END-SELECT.
    EXIT.


This question is similar to: When to use dots in COBOL?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Other people have explained the period.  It's simple grammar.  A period ends a sentence.  In COBOL, a period ends a logical code sequence (a sentence).

A period is the "absolute scope terminator" in COBOL.
It ends a COBOL "sentence" as well.
Your sample does not include it, but a program with that code will always contain DIVISIONs (at least implicitly and in any case per standard COBOL). Let's assume you have PROCEDURE DIVISION as a first line in this code.
Then you have optional SECTIONs (SELECT SECTION. in your case) which can optionally be divided into paragraphs END-SELECT. in your case.
In any case you'll have zero or more "sentences" within those (starting after and ending by a terminator period), which consists of one or more "statements" (your MOVEs).
Looking at your code:
           MOVE xxx TO Bbb
           MOVE ccc TO HHHH
       END-SELECT.

There are the following options:

you compile with a "modern" compiler/dialect which allows "code" at column 8-72 in fixed-form reference-format or in free-form reference-format; in this case the sentence starting with MOVE xxx TO Bbb (after the previous terminator period) ends at END-SELECT, so the second statement is
MOVE ccc TO HHHH END-SELECT.
In this case END-SELECT is expected to be a variable name, you get a compiler error that this isn't defined.
your compiler has COBOL85 fixed-form rules (only "procedures" may start in col 8-11, not the "code") and END-SELECT does start at column 8-11.
In this case you get a compile error that a procedure may only start when the previous one is terminated.
Your compiler may deduce that a terminator period is missing and "implies" it, commonly with a more severe warning.

Note: as the terminator period is also the ultimate scope terminator IF a IF B MOVE C TO D ELSE GOBACK. adding periods after every statement is to be "taken with salt".
If you work in an environment where this is the coding rule - do it that way. Otherwise leave "unneeded" periods out, becauses "periods all over the place" means that you either never "embed" real code in conditions (= if you need a condition you will create a new paragraph, adding an IF condition GO TO new-paragraph.) or you need to remove all the periods of the code you want to put inside the condition.
